# Laravel Eloquent Where Condition from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a list of books titles that appear where a user can leave feedback.

I have 2 tables Books table & feedback table.

The tables are for a site where a user gives feedback on a book, once the user has left feedback for that book, I no longer want the book to appear in the book results for that user, there are many users that will be leaving feedback for the same book.

A book can have many feedback

I want to do somthing like if user already left a feedback in the feedback table, then that book they left feedback for should not appear in the results.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this?

my feedback table looks like this:
   id
   book_id
   rating
   feedback
   user_id

my books table looks like this:
   id
   user_id
   title

I am pulling the books results as follows.

```
$books = Books::where('user_id', $id)->get();
```

I need something that will check condition if the user has left feedback for the book yet, then don't show the books the user has already left feedback for in the results.

Comment: what is `user_id` doing in books table?

Comment: Share Your table schema

Comment: @userNotFound the user_id in the books table is to identify the user who recomended added this book to the list of books to review

Answer (score 0):

Just do a query that where the feedback is empty and if its empty it will have a result and if not of course it will not have a result so use if to ask the feedback if its empty

```php
    $feedback = Feedback::where('user_id', $id)->get();

    $feed = '';

    if(!empty($feedback->feedback)){
        $feed = $feedback;
    }

    return view('yourview')->with('feed', $feed);
```

if you have join table you can do this also. on your upper controller put

```php
    use DB;
```

```php
    $feedback = DB::table('feedback as f')
                ->join('books as b', 'b.id', '=', 'f.book_id')
                ->join('user as u', 'user.id', '=', 'u.id')
                ->where('u.id',$id)
                ->select('u.*','f.*','b.*')->get();

    $feed = '';

    if(!empty($feedback->feedback)){
        $feed = $feedback;
    }

    return view('yourview')->with('feed', $feed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your have relation in your `Books` Modal like this

```
public function feedback(){
 return $this->hasMany(Feedback::class,'book_id','id');
}
```

For getting all the books with user id `$id` which has atleast one feedback your query should be like this

```
 $books = Books::where('user_id', $id)->has('feedback')->get();
```

If you need more filters you can use `whereHas` instead of `has` which will allow you to run more queries.

***Update***

To get Books that doesn't have feedbacks from user with userid `$id` will like this.

```
 $books = Books:: whereDoesntHave('feedback',function($q) use($id){
  $q->where('user_id',$id);
})->get();
```

But if you like to get all the books of a user with id `$id` and also he hasn't and also doesn't have any feedback from him

```
 $books = Books::where('user_id', $id)-> whereDoesntHave('feedback',function($q) use($id){
      $q->where('user_id',$id);
    })->get();
```

Comment: I want to do the opposite , only show books that don't have feedback from that user.